# Show transparent UINavigationbar will see black bar when swipe the viewController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a `UINavigationController` with 3 viewControllers. We know the three viewControllers share a common navigationBar.If I want to set the `navigationBar` totally transparent. I can put the code in `viewWillAppear`:

```
 [self.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
 [self.navigationBar setShadowImage:[UIImage new]];
 [self.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
  self.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
```

and set it back in `viewWillDisappear`:

```
[self setBackgroundImage:nil forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[self setShadowImage:nil];
[self setBarTintColor:THEME_COLOR];
self.translucent = NO;
```

I want to set the `UINavigationBar` translucent only in viewControllerB, so I put the code in viewControllerB. However, when I popToViewController B, I can see a black bar in the top right of the screen. Since the `viewWillAppear` is invocated. It seems can not be solved in my case.

I come out with some methods:

1. use different `UINavigationBar`.
2. use different `UINavigationController`. But `UINavigationController` can not push a new `UINavigationController`
3. Custom `UIView` like `UINavigationBar`.

I think above methos is more complicated。

Any ideas thanks!

Comment: Put your code of `ViewControllerB` and `ViewControllerC`

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by, "Since the `viewWillAppear` is invocated. It seems can not be solved in my case."? Can you restate that differently? And can you add an image of the black bar in the top-right of the screen? It seems odd that you wouldn't see the bar across the entire top of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

That black color you see is the background color of main window. You can set background image or color to your main window from AppDelegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method (That's totally depends with your design of the view controller B) so that you won't see any difference.

Or else

Simply you can use `viewDidAppear` instead of using `viewWillAppear`, but that will have little flick though.